# MySQL return 0 as value if no record found with group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all customer order month wise and i successfully get with my query but i need 0 or null if any customer has no order in any month.

for example:

```
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
|     date     |    customer    |    order    |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| january 2016 | abc            |    2345     |
| Febuary 2016 | abc            |    2234     |
| january 2016 | xyz            |    2345     |
| febuary 2016 | xyz            |   0/null    |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

but my sql query return something like this

```
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
|     date     |    customer    |    order    |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| january 2016 | abc            |    2345     |
| Febuary 2016 | abc            |    2234     |
| january 2016 | xyz            |    2345     |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(so.month, ' ', so.year) months,
  c.customer_name,
  so.qty
FROM
  customer c
JOIN
  (
  SELECT
      o.customer_id,
      MONTHNAME(o.date) MONTH,
      YEAR(o.date) YEAR,
      SUM(o.quantity) qty
  FROM
    sale_order o
  WHERE
    o.order_type = 'kg'
      AND
    o.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
  GROUP BY YEAR(o.date), MONTHNAME(o.date), o.customer_id
) so 
on so.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Comment: Think you are looking for `left join`

Comment: A help table will do, containing all possible months.

Comment: i think left join return all record weather a customer have not any record between given range right? but i want all customer if any one month's order > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the distinct values of month and year, and then left join to the rest of your results like this:

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT(t.month, ' ', t.year) months,
      c.customer_name,
      so.qty
FROM (select distinct MONTHNAME(date) as month,year(date) as year from sale_order
      where date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01') t
INNER JOIN customer c
 ON(1=1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
      o.customer_id,
      MONTHNAME(o.date) MONTH,
      YEAR(o.date) YEAR,
      SUM(o.quantity) qty
  FROM
    sale_order o
  WHERE
    o.order_type = 'kg'
      AND
    o.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
  GROUP BY YEAR(o.date), MONTHNAME(o.date), o.customer_id
) so 
 on (so.customer_id = c.customer_id and
    so.year = t.year and
    so.month = t.month)
```